# What allows or how is this integral performed?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Focusing on a term of an fluid momentum balance, I see that

$$\int_p \frac{G^2}{g} \frac{p}{bt} d\left(\frac{bt}{p}\right) = \frac{G^2}{g} \ln(p_1/p_2)$$

All variables but $p$ are considered constants.  How does this integral work?

Comment: The relevant form is $\int\frac{du}{u} = \log u$. Note also that $\log a-\log b=\log\frac ab$.

Comment: @MPW ah ok u substitution. Integral of 1/x dx is ln x and ln x2 - ln x1 is equal to ln x2/x1. So I need to figure how to equate du?

Comment: Ok I can equate u=bt/p and therefore I have 1/u du

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

as $ p $ is the only variable, we have

$$\frac {p}{bt}d (\frac {bt}{p})=$$

$$pd (\frac {1}{p})=p (-\frac {dp}{p^2})=$$

$$=-\frac {dp}{p}=-d (\ln (p)) .$$